# Sync Outlook Calendar (used at work) and Google Calendar (used for my family) with privacy protected

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I am looking for a solution to sync my Outlook calendar with my Google calendar.

I use Outlook at work. I use Google for family events.  I would like to have a particular kind of sync:

1. From my Google account, I want to see my Outlook calendars in full details.
2. From my Outlook account, I want to see only busy-free info from my Google calendar. This is because my colleagues (on outlook) do not need to know that I go to see a dentist (event on Google), but they need to know that I am out of office so they do not book me a meeting at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an Gmail account for family and an Exchange account for work?

As far as I know, I’m afraid that Outlook doesn’t have sucn a built-in option to sync events between two calendar folders.

As a workaround, you can directly use Exchange calendar but mark personal events as private. So your colleagues will see your status but the title would be just “Private Appointment”.

You can refer to this article: [Make an appointment or meeting private](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-an-appointment-or-meeting-private-dc3898f0-22f5-45c6-8cc8-b4d4db84111d)